# Add Multidex package along my other package

Tags: android, package, manifest

Inside Android Manifest I want to add this line of code :

```
package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication"
```

But I have already the package of my Application there and it seems to me that I **cannot** add the multidex package. What should I do ?

My Android Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="xx.xx.xx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EventCreate"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".EventCreate" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
         -->android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: where have you added android:name in application tag ?

Comment: inside `application` tag

Comment: @KhizarHayat I added in the xml code the android:name.

Comment: you didn't add in above code. can you please update xml after added and then tell me exactly your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<manifest>` package attribute is not what you should be looking at.  You want to tell the android application which subclass of `Application` your app will use as the application.  To do that all you need to do is set the name attribute on the `<application>` element.

On a side note Multidex is generally a nightmare to work with.  I would suggest looking at your dependencies to try to reduce them.  Play Services are is normally a culprit but them do have libraries for individual pieces of functionality. see https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: I deleted Multidex and I just compiled the specific package I want from google play services. So, now I do not have any problem with 64K methods. Thanks!